# SQL Server parse json value with special character in nested properties

Tags: json, nested, special-characters, sql-server-2016

I have a json value like this and want to query it with SQL Server:

```
declare @buffer nvarchar(max)={"request": {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0" } }
```

I searched and found that, for special values in json properties we can use ""

but it won't work for second and nested levels like user-agent in here

```
select json_query(@buffer,'$.request."user-agent"')
```

It works if json value like this:

```
select json_query(@buffer,'$."req-uest"')
```

but not in this level:

```
declare @buffer nvarchar(max)='{"request": {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0" } }'

select json_query(@buffer,'$.request."user-agent"')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are returning a single value rather than an array or object, you should use [`JSON_VALUE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921890.aspx#Compare%20JSON_VALUE%20and%20JSON_QUERY) instead of `JSON_QUERY`:

```
select json_value(@buffer,'$.request."user-agent"')
```